# How to debug Siri extension in 'Type to Siri' mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, sirikit

There is an option in iOS 11 global preferences: **General/Accessibility/Type to Siri**. If it is enabled, when you open Siri it shows you a text field into which you can type your request instead of saying it.

This option works fine when I run Siri with the device's home button. But when Siri is started through the Xcode's bebug session of my extension, the textfield is not shown and I need to speak to it.

Is there a way to force siri to be opened it the Type mode when started from the Xcode debugger?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround:

When you start Siri from the debugger, wait for it to show you the label 'What can I help you with?'. Then tap on this label and drag it to the bottom of the screen and release it there. The label will disappear and the textfield 'Type to Siri' will be shown.

For this trick to work you still have to enable **General/Accessibility/Type to Siri** option in iOS preferences.

Alternatively, if you want to debug your Siri extension with a specific fixed query, you can set it as a debug schema parameter. Click on your intent extension schema, click edit schema, Run debug > Info tab> Siri Intent Query
[image]